# System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain any definition for 'ToList'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the problem. I am getting IEnumerable from ViewPage and when I tried it to convert List it is showing me error like:

> '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Pax_Detail>`' does not contain
>   a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Pax_Detail>`' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit_Booking(Booking model, IEnumerable<Pax_Detail> pax)
{
  List<Pax_Detail> paxList = new List<Pax_Detail>();
  paxList = pax.ToList(); //getting error here
  BookingDL.Update_Booking(model, paxList);
  return View();
}
```

I have applied same logic on another controller. And it is working fine. I don't know what problem it has. I have already clean, rebuild project and also restarted my laptop(though it was needed).

Comment: Have you referenced `System.Core.dll`?

Comment: as a side note, avoid `= new List<Pax_Detail>()` when overwriting it in the next line with `pax.ToList()`, because unused memory is allocated this way

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Are you missing a  using directive for `System.Linq`?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist

Comment: Oh thanks. I am not using Linq in my project but I think it is needed in this case.

Comment: I would recommend using resharper. It's brilliant at spotting things like this and would prompt you to add the using directive.

Comment: @AndyNichols That functionality is implicit to Visual Studio already. Perhaps it wasn't in 2013 :)

Answer (score 38):

You're missing a reference to System.Linq.

Add

```
using System.Linq
```

to get access to the ToList() function on the current code file.

---

To give a little bit of information over why this is necessary, `Enumerable.ToList<TSource>` is an extension method. Extension methods are defined outside the original class that it targets. In this case, the extension method is defined on `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to adding LINQ would be to use this code instead:

```
List<Pax_Detail> paxList = new List<Pax_Detail>(pax);
```

Comment: Super helpful if you're trying to do this in the Immediate Window while debugging a file that is missing the directive.

Comment: When i try this any change in pax is reflected in paxList too!

Answer (score 4):

I was missing System.Data.Entity dll reference and problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had copied some code from another project that was using Automapper - took me ages to work that one out. Just had to add automapper nuget package to project.