# could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

how to solve that problem

when use textbox and html table using same view form then show a error message in browser:

> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'BankName' and no extension method 'BankName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

my code is:

```
@model IEnumerable<pos.Models.dbmodel.Bank>
```

Comment: I think we need to see more of you model and code to be able to answer, and also I'm sure that there are answers to this question if you search a bit. Such as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812913/system-collections-generic-ienumerable-does-not-contain-any-definition-for-tol

Comment: this example is not same.

Comment: actually problem is that view form . when use both html & textbox in view page then error show. when use only html table then project run successfully.

Comment: Are you typing @Model.BankName somewhere in your code? (besides, posting the whole code would help)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your issue is this. You have the following model declared in the view:

`@model IEnumerable<pos.Models.dbmodel.Bank>`

But somewhere in the view you are using accessing `BankName` like this:

`Model.BankName`

Without seeing more of your view code it's hard to say, but that would be my guess. In order to access `BankName` you need to iterate through the model e.g.

```
@foreach(var bank in Model)
{
    <p>@bank.BankName</p>
}
```